# Failed to extract foundry config:

Tags: error, foundry, forge

I am currently creating a new project using foundry(used hardhat before this) and I am currently getting this error when I run forge build:
failed to extract foundry config:
foundry config error: stream did not contain valid UTF-8 in Remapping Provider.

I have no idea what is going on. I believe I installed everything I need to run Forge?
Thank you in advance!

This is my foundry.toml file:

```
         [profile.default]
    src = "src"
    out = "artifacts"
    libs = ["lib"]
    remappings = [
       "@openzeppelin/=lib/@openzeppelin-contracts/",
       "eth-gas-reporter/=node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/",
       "hardhat-deploy/=node_modules/hardhat-deploy/",
       "hardhat/=node_modules/hardhat/",
    ]

    # See more config options https://github.com/foundry- 
    rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/config/README.md#all-options
```

This is my remappings.txt file:

```
    @openzeppelin/=lib/@openzeppelin-contracts/
    eth-gas-reporter/=node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/
    hardhat-deploy/=node_modules/hardhat-deploy/
    hardhat/=node_modules/hardhat/
    @openzeppelin/contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/
    ds-test/=lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/
    erc4626-tests/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/lib/erc4626-tests/
    forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/
    openzeppelin-contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
```

Comment: Give more info regarding the error

Comment: I updated my post. I uploaded my remappings file and foundry.toml file